# IntentService starting my app

Tags: android, android-activity, intentservice

I have an IntentService that runs every 5 minutes. The problem i'm having is when the user is out of the app, the service starts the app up. How can i specify to the service that the app should not be started? It doesn't have the desired effect at the moment as the user could be texting when the app is started.

How i start the service.

```
// get a Calendar object with current time
             Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
             // add 5 minutes to the calendar object
             cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
             Intent intent = new Intent(EntryActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
             intent.putExtra("alarm_message", "sending outstanding transactions");
             // In reality, you would want to have a static variable for the request code instead of 192837
             PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(EntryActivity.this, 192837, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

             // Get the AlarmManager service
             AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
             //am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
             //43200000 = 12 hours
             //3600000 = 1hr
             //1800000 = 30 mins
             //300000 = 5 mins

             am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 300000 , sender);
```

The receiver.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   try {

     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
     String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");
    // Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, SendOutstandingTransactions.class);
     myIntent.setAction("com.carefreegroup.startatboot.MyService");
     context.startService(myIntent);

    } catch (Exception e) {
     Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     e.printStackTrace();

    }
 }

}
```

.

```
public class SendOutstandingTransactions extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = SendOutstandingTransactions.class.getSimpleName();
    NfcScannerApplication nfcscannerapplication;
    Cursor c;
    //LocationManager             mlocManager;
    //LocationListener            mlocListener;
    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs;
    Editor  prefsEditor;
    String companyID;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication)getApplication();
        //mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SendOutstandingTransactions.this.getApplicationContext());
        prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();

    }





    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        companyID = null;
        ContentValues messageValues = null;
        ContentValues phoneNumbers = null;
        c = nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.queryAllFromCarer();
        String carerId = null;
        if(c != null && c.getCount() > 0){

        c.moveToLast();

         carerId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_CARER_ID));
        companyID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_COMP_ID));
        }

        //check to see if this service has run before
        Cursor howManyRuns = nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.queryAllFromBackgroundServicesTable();

        if(howManyRuns.getCount() > 0){
            //service has run at least once before
            //do nothing

        }else{

            String hasRunOnce = "true";
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(LoginValidate.C_BACKGROUNDSERVICES_HAVE_RUN_ONCE, hasRunOnce);
            nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.insertIntoBackgroundServicesTable(cv);

        }


        Log.e(TAG, "inside onHandleIntent and about to do the service stuff");

        if(nfcscannerapplication.getSignalStrength() > 0 && isOnline() == true){


            DateTime now = new DateTime();
            now = now.minusDays(3);
            nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.deleteTransactionsOlderThanSpecificTime(now);
            nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.sendOutstandingTransactions();
            nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.checkCompanyOptions();

            nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.deleteTablePhone();
            phoneNumbers = nfcscannerapplication.loginWebservice.getCompanyPhonenumbers(companyID);

    ..................
..................
    ..................
```

[edit1]

```
// get a Calendar object with current time
             Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
             // add 5 minutes to the calendar object
             cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
             intent.putExtra("alarm_message", "sending outstanding transactions");
             // In reality, you would want to have a static variable for the request code instead of 192837
             PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 192837, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

             // Get the AlarmManager service
             AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
             //am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
             //43200000 = 12 hours
             //3600000 = 1hr
             //1800000 = 30 mins
             //300000 = 5 mins

             am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 150000 , sender);
```

Comment: What do You mean by 'that should not be started'? Is the service part of Your app?

Comment: @sandrstar Hi yes the service will check the app's DB for any outstanding transactions, if there are any it will send them to a web service. None of this needs an activity to be shown. the idea was all this would be done in the background.

Comment: Sorry i meant how can i specify to the service that the app should not be started

Comment: If an activity is appearing, it is because you are calling `startActivity()` somewhere.

Comment: can you try with `ApplicationContext`  in place of `EntryActivity.this` at the time of creation of `intent` and getting calling `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar hi i've initialized the service now in EDIT1. it has not made a difference unless i have not done what you intended?

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi, i can't see anywhere that a call to startActivity is done. Once the service is initialized the subsequent classes that are called as part of the service are just POJOs, they don't extend activity and i can't see a call to an activity within them

Comment: not sure what the problem is; can you try using `PendingIntent.getService` in place of `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` since your broad receiver is only starting the service...

Comment: is AlarmReceiver separate class? Is it defined in the manifest?

Comment: @CommonsWare There was a floor in my logic where i tested the contents of a contentsValues. This did in fact lead to a call to an Activity. If you'd like to create an answer i'll accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: @sandrstar Praful Bhatnagar Thanks for your help but it's solved. The answer is in the comment by CommonsWare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an activity to appear on the screen, something had to call `startActivity()`. Sometimes figuring out *what* is calling `startActivity()`, and *why*, can be problematic. But, usually there is only a couple of places in your code where you are starting any given activity, and so via breakpoints, `Log` statements, or the like, you can usually track down the culprit.

In the absence of a `startActivity()` call, broadcasts and started services will be purely in the background, even if the process contains activity instances from before.